# Summing UP rows in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle (12c) table like below:

| ID | Amt | Identifier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 50 | 20210331 |
| ABC | 125 | 20210331 |
| ABC | 75 | 20201205 |
| ABC | 100 | 20210401 |
| DEF | 50 | 202103AA |
| DEF | 125 | 202103BB |
| DEF | 75 | 202012BB |
| DEF | 500 | 202104AC |

I need the total amount for col1 and the first row of the identifier as below in Oracle SQL

| ID | Amt | Identifier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 350 | 20210331 |
| DEF | 750 | 202103AA |

Table structure:

ID varchar2

Amt  Number

Idenfier varcahr2

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "first" when you say "first row of the identifier"? (You almost surely mean "identifier value in the first row", there are no "rows of identifiers" in your table; but that still doesn't explain what **first** mean.) Note that in Gordon Linoff's answer, he just selects the least identifier - but that contradicts the (presumably desired) output you posted in your question.

Comment: I mean first the appearance of Identifier column value when the ID changes along with the SUM(Amt)

Comment: You don't seem to understand the question. When we display rows they appear in some (random!) order, because we can't show them on top of each other; but in a database, rows don't have a "natural" ordering within a given ID. There is no "first" or "second" or "third" appearance. "first" or "second" etc. when you order them by **what**? That's what I mean. Think of golf balls in a basket - which one is "first" or "second" etc.? You need to think about rows in a table the same way. They are ordered only when **you** specify an ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for aggregation?

```
select id, sum(amt), min(identifier)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: `min(identifier)` will not produce the "desired output" the OP posted in his question. In fact what he shows is neither the `min` nor the `max`, in either case. It is "first row" (as he said in the question), in some undefined way. Did you notice that? If so, I don't see any mention of it in your reply. If you didn't see it - why not? Did you look?